# What is "iTunes Device Support Upgrade"?

Tags: software-update

What I know:

- Component of "Software Update" (and is visible when you open the list).
- Requires reboot
- 108 MB (for Sierra)
- is hidden in the "Updates Installed in Last 30 days list
- (probably) is not part of the auto-installing "Install system data and security updates" track

First appeared with "macOS Mojave 10.14.5, Security Update 2019-003 High Sierra, Security Update 2019-003 Sierra".

Tried Apple sites and some basic googling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iTunes Device Support Update addressed a rare issue that could cause problems with updating and/or restoring devices through iTunes on macOS. This update was not required for Windows versions of iTunes.

This update was recommended for any macOS users who use iTunes to update or restore their iOS devices. It ensures that these updates/restores work properly.

**[UPDATE]**

Below is a screenshot taken from the Mac App Store app running within El Capitan showing the iTunes Device Support Update and its description:

[image]

Comment: Do you have a source for this? Are there any more details with what the problem was that this overcomes (I understand the precise fix is likely not shared)?

Comment: I had just started using iTunes for backup, because iCloud is full. Are the problems only with restore/update, or would they have affected my backup?

Comment: Apologies @grg - only just saw your comment. Fair question! The description in the App Store states: *"This update ensures proper updating and restoring for iOS devices using iTunes for Mac."?* - Unfortunately, a direct download of the `MobileDeviceSU.pkg` package for this update doesn't include any details. I'll see if I can get in front of a Mac that hasn't been updated yet so I can take a screenshot and add it to my answer.

Comment: @benc Yes, my understanding is this issue affects software updates and iOS restores for particular devices - but only in rare circumstances. I did try getting more info from Apple, but all I could get is that backups themselves are not affected, but if you *were* affected by this issue it's possible that a restore from your backup may not be 100% successful. Based on your question I assume you've installed the update, so if you were affected you'd be fine now.

Comment: @grg Screenshot added as promised. :)